# Can signed bytes be read from a stream?

Tags: java, c#, servlets, stream

I'm trying to read bytes sent by a java servlet into a C# application, so far, I haven't been able to get anything more than gibberish from the servlet using normal streams in C#. I've tried various forms of decoding, but haven't found a working way to read sbytes into a c# application from an http source.

The servlet bytes are sent with

**Edited Code**

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    ServletOutputStream resp = response.getOutputStream();
    try{
        resp.write("test".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        //Do Nothing
    }
```

C# reads in with

```
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://path.to/servlet");
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "text/html";
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            string text;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(text);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
```

I end up with two question marks or the same two ascii symbols.

Does anyone have any idea how to do stream these Java bytes into a C# application?

Comment: Seems like your question is more related with encoding not signed bytes. Have you tried `Encoding.UTF8` ?

Comment: `"test".getBytes()` will give the same result. Just sayin'.

Comment: @L.B thanks, I have tried UTF8, no change other than that I get black diamond question marks rather than two ascii characters.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

- You're using the platform-default encoding in both C# and Java. That's almost always a bad choice. Specify the encoding explicitly in Java - UTF-8 is usually a good choice. (That's also the default for most .NET code.)
- You're ignoring the return value of `Stream.Read`; in general you should use that to work out how much data you've actually received. In this case, however, it would be a *much* better idea to use `StreamReader`:

  ```
  string text;
  // Uses UTF-8 implicitly
  using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
  {
      text = reader.ReadToEnd();
  }
  ```

The signedness of bytes in Java is irrelevant here.

(Additionally, why are you using `new String("test")`? What do you think that will do over just using `"test"`?)

Comment: Also without a help of a class like *StreamReaer*, using return value may still give incorrect chars since a 2 byte-char may be splitted between *read*s

Comment: @L.B: True. You could use `Decoder` directly, but `StreamReader` would be a much better option.

Comment: I'm still getting two diamond question marks as a response... I posted the updated code above though in a more complete form, to see if anything important might have been left out and reflecting your suggested changes. (The original string was a big more complicated, I simplified it to just "test" when I switched from a Java client to a C# client, and I found that it wasn't working.)

Comment: @user3344497: I suggest you look at what's happening at the network level. It's possible that the response is being compressed, for example. Use Wireshark to look at network traffic.